# Which EMF frequncies provide power to field powered implants?

Tags: emf

What EMF frequencies provide power to field powered implants? There are in ear phones and some implants which obtain power through EMF fields. They produce sound in the ear and some other implants are used to track locations of animals and people. They don't have any power source like batteries, etc. So where do these devices get power from? What EMF frequencies provide power to these devices?

Comment: Can you provide examples?

Comment: @Lior: I think the OP is referring to subcutaneous (under the skin) implants such as hearing aid implants that have no internal batteries but transmit power from an external device (where batteries can easily be replaced) through the skin and into the internal device. One of my nieces has one with a magnet under the skin behind her ear. The external device is held in place by magnet and both power and audio are coupled through the skin to power, I think, a 16-pole stimulator which was implanted in her ear canal. But for animals? Do they recharge them back at base?

Comment: @LiorBilia I had something like this in mind: COOMAX Mini Spy Earpiece Invisible Earphone. But what really prompted me to ask this question was reports that government was experimenting with implants in the ear in unsuspecting victims. I thought it could be used for brain washing once it's implanted in ear.

Comment: @Transistor Can you please search Amazon for COOMAX Mini Spy Earpiece Invisible Earphone and tell me if earphones like these require a loop to be worn around neck, or the EMF which the loop produces can be generated from distance, eliminating the need for wearing the loop. If yes how far can the power source be. If EMF is used to prove power to these earphone, on what frequencies do they get their audio signal on? Are these earphones made with nanotechnology?

Comment: Sorry, no. If you want me to look at something then please provide a link. If it's relevant to the question then post it in the question, not in the comments. Note that "Mini Spy Earpiece Invisible Earphone" isn't an implant.

Comment: @Transistor I thought about posting a link to it then I thought StackExchange may not allow external links so I just wrote it's name. It's true Mini Spy Earpiece is not an implant, but it's so small(it's about the size of a lentil) it can be implanted or a government agency might create such an implant to be placed under skin.

Comment: There is no problem posting links if they are not spam. They're usually essential. I think you're wandering off into conspiracy fantasy here. I'd rather stick to technical questions.

Comment: @Transistor Would you say the due diligence you exercise when you check the expiry date on a consumable you buy to be due to conspiracy fantasy? If not, then don't call my valid suspicions conspiracy fantasy.

Comment: @Transistor Anyway, here is the link to the product: https://www.amazon.com/COOMAX-Earpiece-Invisible-Earphone-Covert/dp/B00XT3X0I4                      You can see how small the earpiece is, it could easily be implanted, instead of wearing that ring around neck to power it, can they be supplied with signals and power through a nearby device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What EMF frequencies provide power to field powered implants?

According to [this review](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx7/6287639/8600701/08576513.pdf) in 2019, the following frequencies have been used for [inductive power transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer#Inductive_coupling) to implantable medical devices:-

10 KHz, 25.5 KHz, 134 KHz, 200 KHz, 700 KHz, 1 MHz, 1.5 MHz, 2 MHz, 2.5 MHz, 6.8 MHz, 8 MHz, 13.56 MHz, 20 MHz,  25 MHz, 40 MHz, 50 MHz, 100~250 MHz, 460 MHz.

The most popular frequency was 13.56 MHz.

> where do these devices get power from?

Cochlear implants have an external part similar to a hearing aid, which contains the wireless power transmitter. These are powered by a battery.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Are there any other frequencies which can be used or only these?